Occasional hang on boot, Ubuntu 22.04
I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 On a Surface Go 2, along with the linux-surface Kernel. Everything has been working great for ~ a year, but recently my tablet has started to often hang on boot. After 2-3 force-shut and boot again it normally manages to boot.
I have looked at the boot logs by running journalctl -b -0 and journalctl -b -1, to compare a successful boot and a failed one. Both the failed and successful boots contain the line systemd[1]: Startup finished in 3.138s (firmware) + 4.866s (loader) + 4.772s (kernel) + 20.036s (userspace) = 32.814s. which makes me think that the start-up process goes quite far (?). Right after that, the failed boot displays the following error (which is absent in the successful boot):
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[833]: KMS: DRM_IOCTL_MODE_CREATE_DUMB failed: No such device
gnome-shell[833]: Failed to lock front buffer on /dev/dri/card0: gbm_surface_lock_front_buffer failed

These two lines repeat a few times, and the log ends with these two lines:
systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Deactivated successfully.

(maybe that's simply me force-shutting the surface).
I have fully updated the system via apt but it did not solve it.
Unlike many similar issues, I do not have an Nvidia GPU.
Any ideas on what's going on and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT:
I am managing to boot consistently with nomodeset, however setting i915.modeset=1 makes boot hang again.

It seems I managed to solve the issue. From the grub setup in /etc/default/grub I have removed the quiet splash options. Now boot displays all the processes happening, but hasn't been hanging anymore. Very unsure how that made a difference!
